# In what scope does the initialization variable of for loops reside?

Tags: javascript, scope

I was thinking about scoping in JS and tried the following code:

```js
let a = 1;
for (let a of [2,3,4]) {
    let a = 5;
}
```

I expected this to throw an error along the lines of `Redeclaration of let a` as I assumed that the `let a` from the for loop would clash with either the inner or outer `let a`. But it didn't.

So I tried the following to be sure it wasn't declared in the parent scope:

```js
let a = -1;
for (let a = 0; a < 5; a++) {
    console.log(a);
}
console.log(a)
# Result: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, -1
```

So it clearly isn't declared there, but if I add `let a = 4` in the for loop the result just changes to:

```js
# Result: 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, -1
```

So my question is, do the declared variables within the for loop have their own scope? How does this work?

Comment: @Yousaf Damn. I really did look for an asnwer but couldn't find it. Thanks!

Comment: If you want detailed steps of how different scopes are created for the for loop, read [this article](https://yousaf.hashnode.dev/understanding-closures-in-loops-problem-and-how-it-is-solved-in-es6), specifically, the steps at the end of the article.

Answer (score -2):

**Scope rules in JS**

Any variables declared inside a block belong to that particular block and become local variables.

A function in JS defines a scope for variables declared using var, let and const. Any variable declared within that function is only accessible from that function and any nested functions.

A code block (if, for, etc.) defines a scope only for variables declared with the let and const keywords. The var keyword is limited to function scope, meaning that new scope can only be created inside functions.

The let and const keywords have block scope, which creates a new, local scope for any block where they’re declared. You can also define standalone code blocks in JavaScript, and they similarly delimit a scope:

```
{
  // standalone block scope
}
```

Function and block scopes can be nested. In such a situation, with multiple nested scopes, a variable is accessible within its own scope or from inner scope. But outside of its scope, the variable is inaccessible.

In JS, variables with the same name can be specified at multiple layers of nested scope. In such a situation, local variables gain priority over global variables. If you declare a local variable and a global variable with the same name, the local variable will take precedence when you use it inside a function or block. This type of behavior is called shadowing. Simply put, the inner variable shadows the outer.

That’s the exact mechanism used when a JS interpreter is trying to find a particular variable. It starts at the innermost scope being executed at the time, and continues until the first match is found, no matter whether there are other variables with the same name in the outer levels or not.

Credits to the author of [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/#:%7E:text=A%20function%20in%20JavaScript%20defines,the%20let%20and%20const%20keywords.) blog post.

---

**Going deep into scope rules for a for loop in JS**

```
for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])
   statement
```

**initialization**
An expression (including assignment expressions) or variable declaration evaluated once before the loop begins. Typically used to initialize a counter variable. This expression may optionally declare new variables with *var* or *let* keywords. Variables declared with *var* are not local to the loop, i.e. they are in the same scope the for loop is in. Variables declared with *let* are local to the statement.

The result of this expression is discarded.

**condition**
An expression to be evaluated before each loop iteration. If this expression evaluates to true, statement is executed. This conditional test is optional. If omitted, the condition always evaluates to *true*. If the expression evaluates to *false*, execution skips to the first expression following the for construct.

**final-expression**
An expression to be evaluated at the end of each loop iteration. This occurs before the next evaluation of condition. Generally used to update or increment the counter variable.

**statement**
A statement that is executed as long as the condition evaluates to true. To execute multiple statements within the loop, use a block statement (`{ /* ... */ }`) to group those statements. To execute no statement within the loop, use an empty statement (`;`).

Credits to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for#Parameters) docs.

Comment: All of this is taken [from here](https://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/)

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I was asking specifically about the initialization variable in for loops, not how scoping in general works in JS

Comment: What is the problem with taking information from internet and filtering the most relevant part to the OP ?

Comment: The no attribution is the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing

Comment: @VLAZ I added the credits at the end of the answer. Thanks for the remind

Comment: @KerwinSneijders The for loop defines a local scope. Isn't the behavior you see explained by the js local scope rules mentioned in my answer ?

Comment: @JohnDoe Not as far as I can tell. The for loop defines a scope for everything within its body BUT it also creates a scope for the initialization part of the loop. That particular part is what I was asking about :)

Comment: @KerwinSneijders I added an explanation about that at the end of my answer. This plus the explanation about js scope rules should be a complete explanation to your question :) Please, check it

Comment: @JohnDoe That explanation is incorrect, the variables aren't in the scope the for loop is in, the for loop resides in the 'global' scope in my case. The variables reside in scopes created per iteration because I use `let`. It's explained well in the linked article in the question comments [here](https://yousaf.hashnode.dev/understanding-closures-in-loops-problem-and-how-it-is-solved-in-es6). (Thanks Yousaf for linking & writing it)

Comment: @KerwinSneijders Indeed. I updated the answer to explain the difference between declaring the variables with var or let in the for loop. The explanation to your question is a subset of my answer now. So, please, consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: I have to disagree with you. You basically copy pasted 2 articles/sites in a row. It does eventually answer my question but it is everything **but** a nice concise answer. The answer linked as "Already has an answer" at the top is a nice concise explanation together with the link Yousaf shared in the comments of the question.

Comment: @KerwinSneijders I summarized the information I found on the internet, which by the way appeared on the first pages of a simple google search. If you think it's bad to copy paste from internet, you should also think it's bad to ask a question that can be solved with some minutes of google search.

Comment: @JohnDoe Didn't mean it in a negative way. Just saying that this answer covers way more than what my specific question asked for. If I knew what I was looking for exactly I'd have been able to find it a lot easier with just some searching but I didn't. I also couldn't find a question about it on SO, so I thought it would be a good idea to create one.